# Pandas: how to agg(f) on the column axis (Multiindex) with f as dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that I concat with itself. This leads to dupliacted columns with floats and strings. I would like to aggregate the columns with identical names. The columns with floats have to be summed, while for the columns with strings, I keep the first, or the last or whatever.

Of course, I can remove the string columns prior and reintegrate it after the `.groupby().sum()`... but this is heavy and I guess I can do better.

Thanks for your help.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

iterables_1 = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo'], ['one', 'two']]
iterables_2 = [['baz', 'foo', 'foz'], ['one', 'two']]

names = ['first', 'second']
# transform it to tuples
columns_1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables_1, names=names)
columns_2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables_2, names=names)

# indices
index_1 = range(0, 5, 1)
index_2 = range(2, 9, 1)

# data: df_1 filled with 1, df_2 filled with 2
data_1 = [[1] * 6] * 5 #np.random.randn(5, 6)
data_2 = [[2] * 6] * 7 #np.random.randn(7, 6)

# build two multi-index DataFrame from it
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_1, columns=columns_1, index=index_1,
                    dtype='float64')
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_2, columns=columns_2, index=index_2,
                    dtype='float64')

# Merging the two DataFrames by summing works like a charm
tmp = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)
levels = ('first', 'second')
tmp = tmp.groupby(level=levels, axis=1)
df_3 = tmp.sum()

# Issue: if one string column is in one or both of the df, how to handle it ?
df_4 = df_1.copy(deep=True)
df_4[('col', 'str')] = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

# This time, it does not work...
tmp = pd.concat([df_4, df_2], axis=1)
levels = ('first', 'second')
tmp = tmp.groupby(level=levels, axis=1)
df_5 = tmp.sum()

# Tried with .agg as well...
f = {('col', 'str'): 'first', df_3.columns:'sum'}
df_5 = tmp.agg(f)
```

Expected result:

```
first   bar       baz       foo       foz       col
second  one  two  one  two  one  two  one  two  str
0       1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0    A
1       1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0    B
2       1.0  1.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  2.0    C
3       1.0  1.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  2.0    D
4       1.0  1.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  2.0    E
5       0.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  nan
6       0.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  nan
7       0.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  nan
8       0.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  nan
```

Comment: Can you please mock up the expected dataframe?

Comment: Well, it would be almost the same as ```df````. Only the values will be higher. I will change a bit the example soit is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated

For specified format. Just need to `groupby()` multi index columns

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate data (copied from pandas example)
arrays=[['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], columns=index)

# Removing that line makes the code works
df[('associated line', 'daily')] = np.array(['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

tmp = pd.concat([df, df], axis=1)

# just need to aggregate by the multiindex columns.  cannot pass
# dict to agg() when axis=1.  string columns are concatenated
df2 = tmp.groupby(tmp.columns, axis=1).sum()
# re-establish multiindex after agg turned into index of tuples
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df2.columns)
print(df2.to_string())
```

**output**

```
  associated line       bar                 baz                 foo                 qux          
            daily       one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
A              AA  1.480340  0.218342  1.414930  0.315473 -0.020245  3.197697  1.413613  1.993694
B              AA -0.600906  1.946283  2.134399 -3.224025 -0.060312 -1.524952  1.090953  0.640910
C              BB  2.383411  1.677919  0.913879 -1.960266  1.445124  0.770229 -0.068034 -0.128026
A              CC -1.019629 -1.739387  2.756562 -1.594042  1.363063  1.762273  0.404269 -3.105941
```

### Previous answer

The issue is really after the `concat()` the column names are duplicated

1. rebuild multilevel column index adding level (0 or 1)
2. dynamically build `dict` that is used by `agg()`

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate data (copied from pandas example)
arrays=[['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], columns=index)

# Removing that line makes the code works
df[('associated line', 'daily')] = np.array(['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

tmp = pd.concat([df, df], axis=1)

# build tuple list that gives unique columns for tmp dataframe
a = [tuple([0]) + k for k,v in tmp.dtypes[:len(tmp.dtypes)//2].items()] + \
    [tuple([1]) + k for k,v in tmp.dtypes[:len(tmp.dtypes)//2].items()]
tmp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(a)
# sum for floats, first for other data types
myagg = {k:"sum" if v.type==np.float64 else "first" for k,v in tmp.dtypes.items()}
df2 = tmp.groupby(level=0).agg(myagg)

print(df2.to_string())
```

**output**

```
          0                                                                                               1                                                                                      
        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux           associated line       bar                 baz                 foo                 qux           associated line
        one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two           daily       one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two           daily
A -0.921217 -0.174036 -0.255332 -2.634349  0.521639 -1.650088 -1.267090  3.480850               A -0.921217 -0.174036 -0.255332 -2.634349  0.521639 -1.650088 -1.267090  3.480850               A
B  1.852300  0.762291  1.671279 -0.552787  1.400132  1.382381  0.274379 -1.367210               A  1.852300  0.762291  1.671279 -0.552787  1.400132  1.382381  0.274379 -1.367210               A
C -0.615653  0.830172  0.435599 -0.272941 -0.042506  0.664967  0.399778 -0.464236               B -0.615653  0.830172  0.435599 -0.272941 -0.042506  0.664967  0.399778 -0.464236               B
```

Comment: Well, I updated my post so it is clearer. This is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @AntoineCollet I've updated answer.  Really none of these challenges would come if you did `concat(df, df, axis=0)`. I guess you are doing this to synthesise an actual requirement you are solving

Comment: Thank you for this answer ! Absolutely, I just try to find the most robust way to perform some DataFrame merging in production code.

Comment: I wonder if dict(slice('bar', :, :) = "mean") wouldn't work in the agg function?